# How to export all Google Docs in a folder in one single PDF?

Tags: google-drive, export, pdf

I have a folder with hundreds of short Google docs (product descriptions).
I am wondering if there is an easy way (like "push button") to export all these in a PDF that simply assemble all the PDF into one single document.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is no integrated Google Drive feature for that at the moment. Essentially what you are trying is exporting server-side merged files. What you could do instead is download all the files in questions (in PDF for instance) and merge them locally. There are applications like [pdfsam](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfsam/) that can help you do that.

Answer (score 0):

https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout/custom should do the trick.

I apologies for the late reply.

Comment: Could you please post the relevant parts of the answer here.  Answers that are just a link are not very helpful.